# Send SQL Queries from JavaScript to a database with the VSC extension

Tags: javascript, sql-server, visual-studio-code

so I use the VSC extenstion and connected a database to it. In the SQL-Query window I can already send queries to the database I want to.
Now I want to make a simple button in HTML that then activates JavaScript code which inputs a query like 'SELECT * FROM customer' to the SQL-Query window or sends it directly to the database.

Since I never connected JavaScript to a Database or used the SQL extension in such a way, I am not sure how I would accomplish that.

DB2.sql is not a DB2 type database it´s MSSQL from Microsoft.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUuEv.png)

This is what I imagine the plain button to work like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BnLT.png)

Thanks for the help.